# Нужно ли включать директорию .git в состав репозитория?

Tags: git, gitignore

Настраиваю `vcsh` (version control system for $HOME), базирующуюся на `git`. В книге *Pro Git* и поиском не смог найти ответ на вопрос - нужно ли оставить в составе репозитория директорию с настройками и данными самого git (в общем случае это .git в корне репозитория) или следует внести её в .gitignore для данного репозитория?

В случае именно с `vcsh` - нужно ли хранить рабочую информацию из каталога `~/.config/vcsh/repo.d/` в репозитории или исключить его через `.gitignore`?

**Обновление**

*передаётся, только не весь и отдельным механизмом* - а что именно передается? Мой вопрос всё же конкретно к `vcsh` относится, там аналогичный каталог (`~/.config/vcsh/repo.d/my_repo_name`) имеет вид: `branches/`,  `config`, `description`,  `HEAD`, `hooks/`, `index`, `info/`, `objects/`, `refs/` - настройки и хуки я вижу смысл хранить в репозитории, а остальное?

Comment: *имеет вид: branches ...* — вот это и есть **содержимое** репозитория. включать содержимое репозитория в содержимое репозитория **повторно** — конечно, не стоит (даже если это технически осуществимо).

Comment: Опытным путем выяснилось, что `vcsh` автоматически исключает из состава репозитория директории `branches/` и `refs/` (расположенные в `~/.config/vcsh/repo.d/my_repo_name/`), что, по-видимому, и является штатным поведением для git.

Answer (score 2):

Каталог **.git** является служебным. Изначально он создается командой **git init** или во время клонирования.

На сервер он не передается. Включать в **.gitignore** не требуется.

Каталог **.git** для репозитория может быть только один - в его корневом каталоге. Если же вы видите что в подкаталоге он тоже есть, то лучше его удалить.

Comment: *На сервер он не передается.* - передаётся, только не весь и отдельным механизмом.

Comment: *Каталог .git является служебным* — более того, он и содержит репозиторий. правда, в приложении к *vcsh*, репозиторий хранится не в каталоге `~/.git`, а где-нибудь внутри `~/.config/vcsh` (или чего-нибудь подобного).

Comment: > Если же вы видите что в подкаталоге он тоже есть, то лучше его удалить.

ага и почистить сабмодули.

Comment: @KoVadim, submodules не создают дополнительных каталогов вне репозитория. Каталог .git всегда один и он находится в корне.

Answer (score 0):

Каталог *.git* это и есть репозиторий. Всё, что есть вокруг него — порождается из него. Конечно, сначала происходит обратный процесс, когда пользователь добавляет новые файлы в репозиторий, то они помещаются в *.git*. Но суть тут в том, что из этого каталога можно в любой момент развернуть исходное состояние дерева [исходников] в первозданном виде.

Именно этот каталог выкачивается с сервера, когда вы клонируете удалённые репозиторий. Что именно передаётся на сервер? Считайте, что всё. Не передаются несколько файлов, которые считаются локальными — их минимум.